# JMeter - out of memory on linux RH 7.5

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run a load test for a application. For this i am using JMeter (v4 & v5) on linux Red hat 7.5 Vm with 16GB Ram and 8vCPU power. Goal is to reach 20k Users connected via µ-service.

However during the test runs i get the following errors on the console:
Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread.

Here is my jvm jmeter configuration :
 cat bin/jmeter | grep HEAP

### HEAP             (Optional) Java runtime options for memory management

: "${HEAP:="-Xms1g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"}"

Any ideas?
I tried changing the heap size in jmeter, but that didn't seem to help at all.

Comment: this is error on log :

Answer (score 0):

`unable to create new native thread` is not something you can work around by increasing [JVM Heap](https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space), you're going above **maximum number of threads** threshold which is defined on OS level.

You will need to amend [`nproc` value](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/61334) via [ulimit](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) command or by modifying `/etc/security/limits.conf` file to look like:

```
your_user           soft    nproc          1024
your_user           hard    nproc          32768
```

Reference: [Unable to create new native thread](https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/unable-to-create-new-native-thread)

If you will be still receiving this error after raising maximum number of processes on OS level - most probably you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: I am not root on the VM, how can I modify these limits with my application account?

Comment: You can ramp-up the limits using `ulimit` command, however it will be effective till the end of the session. You can consider adding [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan and increase the limits via [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: $ ulimit -Hu
63382
$ ulimit -Su
4096

Comment: this is my config ulimit soft and hard, i have already error with this config:
$ ulimit -Hu
63382
$ ulimit -Su
4096